# Setting a timezone in the Bluemix log files

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I look at the log files for my application, the entries are listed in UTC. However, I want the entries to reflect my local timezone. Can you customize the time zone for the log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find the information in the documentation. I used the following commands to change the time zone to US Eastern time:

```
cf set-env <app-name> JAVA_OPTS '-Duser.timezone=America/New_York'   
cf restage <app-name>
```

As an alternative, I could have changed the `manifest.yml` file.

Comment: Just to be clear this is only for the Java buildpack, not for Node.