# How to set timezone on bluemix app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm having problems with time values in watson conversation. In the "try now" panel the current time is right (taken with the now() function), but when i use the conversation deployed on bluemix or facebook messenger the time is two hours before. Example:

```
  in "try now" panel -> 13:30
  in bluemix chat -> 11:30
  in facebook messenger -> 11:30
```

Seems like bluemix automatically sets utc +00. How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you UTC+2?  The servers are UTC.  See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914493/setting-a-timezone-in-the-bluemix-log-files

Comment: yes, i'm in utc+2 timezone. I've alredy tried those commands, they work, but don't change anything.

Comment: Might be just timezone.  Look here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-date-and-sys-time-entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.
In the "try now" panel the timezone is automatically recognized. 
The only way to let your app know which is your timezone is to create a variable "timezone":"Europe/Rome" in the context field.

Comment: Can you add please your JSON with example?

Comment: you have to add in the conversation_start node the following code:
{ "context" :{ 
"timestamp" : "Europe/Rome"
};